# Lightbox effect for dropdown menu after selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I did a dropdown menu on my page, getting the html element, work fine.But I want to apply a lightbox effect,like when I select some element from the box appears a like a lightbox in front of my page, right now its just showing on my html, but i would like apply a lightbox effect if possible, I want something similar to this plugin, but what I can see just work in images: http://getuikit.com/docs/lightbox.html

Can someone help me? Or suggest any plugin which does this?

my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/wjLXk/42/

updated one: http://jsfiddle.net/wjLXk/43/

html:

```
<select id="mySelect" onchange="npup.doSelect(this);">
    <option value="">Npup says 'select'</option>
    <!-- the option values are suffixes for the elements to show -->
    <option value="0">show one</option>
    <option value="1">show two</option>
    <option value="2">show three</option>
</select>
<!-- container for any elements that are to be in the game -->
<div id="mySpecialElements">
    <!--  these have ids that end with and index  for easy retrieval in "findeElement" function  below-->
    <div id="npup0" class="hidden">one div</div>
    <div id="npup1" class="hidden">second div</div>
    <div id="npup2" class="hidden">third div</div>
</div>
```

js:

```
window.npup = (function (containerId, baseId) {
    // save the container of your special element
    var elementsContainer = document.getElementById(containerId);
    var baseId = baseId;
    function doSelect(select) {
        // get value of select
        var value = select.value;
        // find element based on the value of the select
        var targetDiv = findElement(value);
        if (!targetDiv) { return;} // didn't find the element, bail
        // do magic..
        hideAll(elementsContainer);
        showElement(targetDiv);
    }
    // retrieve some element based on the value submitted
    function findElement(value) {
        return document.getElementById(baseId+value);
    }
    // hide all element nodes within some parent element
    function hideAll(parent) {
        var children = parent.childNodes, child;
        // loop all the parent's children
        for (var idx=0, len = children.length; idx<len; ++idx) {
            child = children.item(idx);
            // if element node (not comment- or textnode)
            if (child.nodeType===1) {
                // hide it
                child.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    }
    // display a certain element
    function showElement(element) {
        element.style.display = '';
    }
    // hide all on page load (might want some extra logic here)
    hideAll(elementsContainer);

    // export api to use from select element's onchange or so
    return {
        doSelect: doSelect
    };
})('mySpecialElements', 'npup'); // give the routine a container id of your special elements, and the base id of those elements
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly reccomend you to change plugin library for your purposes. Try considering [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) [modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals), it will be much easier:

HTML

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option value="">Npup says 'select'</option>
    <!-- the option values are suffixes for the elements to show -->
    <option value="#myModal1">show one</option>
    <option value="#myModal2">show two</option>
    <option value="#myModal3">show three</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
$('#mySelect').on("change", function(){
    var modalID = $(this).val();
    $(modalID).modal('show')
});
```

See my example here: https://jsfiddle.net/3fkqwej7/

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple example it's just the idea, you will have to work on it to have a complete solution. You will have to use css classes to achieve your goal.

Add a new class to your divs. (`lb` in my example). Write the lightbox css for it. (see `.lb` rule in the css code)

```js
window.npup = (function (containerId, baseId) {
    // save the container of your special element
    var elementsContainer = document.getElementById(containerId);
    var baseId = baseId;
    function doSelect(select) {
        // get value of select
        var value = select.value;
        // find element based on the value of the select
        var targetDiv = findElement(value);
        if (!targetDiv) { return;} // didn't find the element, bail
        // do magic..
        hideAll(elementsContainer);
        showElement(targetDiv);
    }
    // retrieve some element based on the value submitted
    function findElement(value) {
        return document.getElementById(baseId+value);
    }
    // hide all element nodes within some parent element
    function hideAll(parent) {
        var children = parent.childNodes, child;
        // loop all the parent's children
        for (var idx=0, len = children.length; idx<len; ++idx) {
            child = children.item(idx);
            // if element node (not comment- or textnode)
            if (child.nodeType===1) {
                // hide it
                child.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    }
    // display a certain element
    function showElement(element) {
        element.style.display = '';
    }
    // hide all on page load (might want some extra logic here)
    hideAll(elementsContainer);

    // export api to use from select element's onchange or so
    return {
        doSelect: doSelect
    };
})('mySpecialElements', 'npup'); // give the routine a container id of your special elements, and the base id of those elements
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ccc;  
}

.lb {
 position: absolute; /* this will make your div to float above the rest of your content */
 width: 80%;  /* some careful positioning */
 height: 80%;  /* some careful positioning */
 background-color: #fff; /* different background color to show how it would look like*/
 left: 10%; /* some careful positioning */
 top: 10%; /* some careful positioning */
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect" onchange="npup.doSelect(this);">
    <option value="">Npup says 'select'</option>
    <!-- the option values are suffixes for the elements to show -->
    <option value="0">show one</option>
    <option value="1">show two</option>
    <option value="2">show three</option>
</select>
<!-- container for any elements that are to be in the game -->
<div id="mySpecialElements">
    <!--  these have ids that end with and index  for easy retrieval in "findeElement" function  below-->
    <div id="npup0" class="hidden lb">one div</div>
    <div id="npup1" class="hidden lb">second div</div>
    <div id="npup2" class="hidden lb">third div</div>
</div>
```

You may need to write automatic positioning based on lightbox size, add an overlay div below the lightbox and mak sure, the user can close the lightbox.

Comment: thanks a lot man, you clarify the things for me I did a update inserting a fade in effect: http://jsfiddle.net/wjLXk/43/ , but i still put a close button like bootstrap. if u can update with more i will appreciate